# Fill date column by year-month starting from a specific month in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For a dataframe as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date', 'rent_price'])
df['rent_price'] = pred.clip(0., 20.) 

       date  rent_price
    0   NaN       6.347
    1   NaN       6.472
    2   NaN       6.449
    3   NaN       6.532
    4   NaN       6.564
    5   NaN       6.555
    6   NaN       6.448
```

How can I fill `date` columns with `year-month` format starting with `2019-10`?
The expected output is like this:

```
            date       rent_price
    0   2019-10       6.347
    1   2019-11       6.472
    2   2019-12       6.449
    3   2020-01       6.532
    4   2020-02       6.564
    5   2020-03       6.555
    6   2020-04       6.448
```

Please note the length of `date` should be same as `rent_price`'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need strings in YYYY-MM format use [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) with [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html) by lenght of `DataFrame`:

```
df['date'] = pd.date_range('2019-10', freq='M', periods=len(df)).strftime('%Y-%m')
print (df)
      date  rent_price
0  2019-10       6.347
1  2019-11       6.472
2  2019-12       6.449
3  2020-01       6.532
4  2020-02       6.564
5  2020-03       6.555
6  2020-04       6.448
```

If need months periods use [`period_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.period_range.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.period_range('2019-10', freq='M', periods=len(df))
```

Comment: Thank you. The first and second methods generate same results, right?

Comment: @ahbon - no, first are strings, second are periods - [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#time-span-representation)

Comment: Ok I get it. Thanks.